# Sending Sparse Files

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, sockets

I've been messing around with sockets in Python and I'd like to be able to send a sparse image file from one machine to another. As expected, sending a sparse file over a python socket doesn't preserve the sparseness of the file. I'd like to do a sparse tar and send it that way, but I just can't figure it out.

The tarfile module says it supports reading sparse files with the GNU format which doesn't help me for creating them... but the python docs say the Pax format has "virtually no limits". I'm not sure if that means I can create an archive and preserve the sparse file or not using the pax format... I've been trying but I just have no idea how it might work.

If this solution isn't an option, is there any other way to send a sparse file over a socket? I hate to have to call 'tar -xSf' via a system command from my application...

Thanks,

Server

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_NODELAY, 1)
s.bind((socket.gethostname(), 50001))
s.listen(1)

img = open('test.img', 'rb')

client, addr = s.accept()
l = img.read(8192)

while(l):
        client.send(l)
        l = img.read(8192)

img.close()
s.close()
```

Client

```
host = ''
port = 50001

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_NODELAY, 1)
s.connect((host, port))

img = open('./newimg.img', 'wb')

l = s.recv(8192)

while(l):
    img.write(l)
    l = s.recv(8192)

img.close()
s.close()
```

On the server, I make a new sparse file: truncate -s 1G test.img

a du -h shows: 0    test.img

I run my server and client. Here is a du -h on the transferred file: 1.0G   newimg.img

As you can see, it expands the file and it is no longer sparse.

Comment: What do you mean with "doesn't preserver the sparseness of the file"? Is the file altered after you sent it? If so you probably implemented the sending wrong, files shouldn't just change magically. Can you show some code, expected and actual output/input?

Comment: Same as with netcat, scp, rsync, etc. When you send a sparse file without putting it in a tar archive that preserves sparseness and extracting it on the other end, the sparseness isn't preserved and it expands to the full size. Try it out. My code is very simple, I'm just using sockets and iterating over my sends and recvs until the file is fully transferred. If I send completely empty 10GB sparse file from one machine, it's expanded to its full 10GB size on the receiving end. My real question is either how to do sparse files with the tarfile module or how else I can accomplish this

Comment: @syntonym I added an example. Please see my above comment too (not the one directed at TessellatingHeckler)

Comment: There are two ways to do this - 1) come up with a wire protocol that sends groups of (offset, size, data) to represent the chunks of the file that are not sparse, and recreate the file appropriately on the receiving end, or 2) continue to send the entire file as is, but have the receiver detect long runs of zeros and not bother writing them to the output file. Neither approach is trivial, but they shouldn't be too horribly difficult, either. Check the source for something like `rsync` to get further information...

Comment: @user165222 Can you show what problems you had with tar? twalberg is right but simply using tar would probably be easier.

Comment: As far as tar goes, I guess it'd work fine if I called it via a system command... I spent a ton of time trying to figure out if it was possible with the tarfile module to handle sparse files but it seems like it isn't, no matter which format I try. It always came out as the full file size after being added to the archive. I wanted to avoid system commands like this if possible, but tar - xSf works so I might have to.  I'll also try to look at the rsync code to get an example of twalbergs method too.

Answer (score 1):

Holes in files are normally created if you write to the beginning of a file, seek to the end and write there. If you read the file you are reading zeros even if there are holes in the file. When you send the files the literal bytes are sent and of course also read. When you then write the bytes all bytes will be written and it will not happen that the holes are created by the filesystem.

To mitigate that you can first seek the holes in the file, sent where they are, and then send the rest of the file.

The following is not polished but should give you a starting point.

```
import os

f = open(path, "b")
fd = f.fileno()

end = os.stat(fd).st_size
holes = []
offset = os.lseek(fd, 0, os.SEEK_HOLE)
while offset != end:
    end_hole = os.lseek(fd, offset, os.SEEK_DATA)
    holes.append((offset, end_hole))
    offset = end_hole

[open socket and stuff]

# send the holes

socket.write(json.dumps(holes)) # encode appropriately

# send file

f.seek(0)
total = 0
for hole in holes:
    while total < hole[0]:
        l = f.read(8192)
        if len(l) + total > hole[0]:
            socket.write(l[:len(l) + total - hole[0]])
            l.seek(hole[1])
            total += len(1) + total - hole[0]
        else:
            socket.write(l)
            total += len(l)
```

Then on the client side:

```
still_json = True
a = []
l = s.recv(8192)

while(still_json):
    a.append(l)
    if check_json_end(l):
        still_json = False
    else:
        l = s.recv(8192)

holes = parse_json(a) # the last chunk can contain something that is not json
# I asume that a still contains the bytes that are not json

fout = open(outfile, "wb")
total = 0

fout.write(a[0]) # handle the case where the first rest after the json in a is already after a hole

total += len(a[0]) 

for hole in holes:
    while total < hole[0]:
        l = socket.recv(8192)
        if len(l) + total > hole[0]:
            fout.write(l[:len(l) + total - hole[0]])
            fout.seek(hole[1])
            fout.write(l[len(l) + total - hole[0]:])
        else:
            fout.write(l)
        total += len(l)
```

There are probably lots of bugs in it and you should rethink each line, but the general principle should be alright. JSON is of course arbitrarily chosen, there are probably other protocols that are better in that case. You could also create your own.